# Ruby String: store a string containing backslashes and hexadecimal notation

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, data-representation

Couldn't find a better title, so let's be pragmatic:

**Goal:** Check if a PNG is valid by comparing its 8 firsts bytes to a matching string

**Issue:** PNG files should start with **\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n** ([why ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)). Storing this as a String in a variable results in several unexpected behavior:

- Using `"`, `\x1A` is replaced to `\u001A` ([SUBSTITUTE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1a/index.htm))

```rb
s = "\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n"
=> "\x89PNG\r\n\u001A\n"
```

- Using `'`, backslashes are escaped

```rb
s = '\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n'
=> "\\x89PNG\\r\\n\\x1A\\n"
```

- Escaping the Substitute character neither works:

```rb
s = "\x89PNG\r\n\\x1A\n"
=> "\x89PNG\r\n\\x1A\n"
```

- Using `force_encoding` failed:

```rb
s = "\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n".force_encoding('UTF-8')
=> "\x89PNG\r\n\u001A\n"
```

I started this project recently to start working with bytes, so far I'm not disappointed :D

What am I missing ? Should I use single quotes and then `gsub` to filter backslashes ? Should I use bit representation instead of hexa ? 
Ideally, I'd like to have to exact value (in hexa) in my variable, without having to call any method on it

Have a wonderful day !

Comment: Why would you force utf-8 on it? It's a byte stream, not a unicode string. `"\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')`

Comment: Regardless, don't confuse actual content and its representation. Those strings are identical, byte-wise. `"\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n".force_encoding('UTF-8').bytes == "\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT').bytes`

Comment: Ahah, all simply (I'm frustrated not to have see it) ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'm going to spend more time playing with it with that in mind. So if I wan't my script to be more robust, I should compare bytes instead of strings (because they can vary, and bytes in a file header are structured in a predictable way) ?

Comment: Yes, when writing a binary file, it makes more sense to work with binary-ish data than utf-8 strings :)

Comment: I love when things sounds clear like your last reply :D Thanks a lot !

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)` would be more semantically appropriate here.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: naturally. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby unfortunately conflates strings and binary data, but you don't have to in your code. Use pack/unpack instead:

```
data.unpack("C8") == [0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0xd, 0xa, 0x1a, 0xa]
# or
png_header = [0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0xd, 0xa, 0x1a, 0xa].pack("C8")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! `pack` and  `unpack` looks super powerful, I'm gonna have to practice hard before getting good with it !

Answer (score 0):

Following Sergio Tulentsev advises, I decided to compare the signature's bytes inside instance methods. It must not be the best solution  (ima n00b), but here's my code:

```rb
SIGNATURE = "\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n"

# inside the initialize methode 
  raise ArgumentError, 'File is not a PNG' unless self.png_sig?


def png_sig?
  bytes_slice(limit: 7) == SIGNATURE.bytes
end

def bytes_slice(first_byte: 0, limit: -1)
  @content.bytes[first_byte..limit]
end
```